# Is an argument of a function declared when no value is passed?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a general question about the Javascript language.
When I define a function like that:

```
{
  var some_func = function(arg1, arg2) {
    //some code here
  }
}
```

and I pass only the first argument to the function like that:

```
var variable = some_func(a1);
```

is the second argument `arg2` defined but with value of `undefined` or is it entirely `undefined`

Or to paraphrase it: are the parameters of the function simply defined as variables, or object properties, when the function is defined, or is there some dynamic declaration mechanism behind the scenes?

Comment: Why would it get the string value 'undefined'? It will just be undefined.

Comment: so it is either defined or not defined?

Comment: To be or not to be... Are you trying to test if the a value was given?  This is often checked by testing if the argument can be asserted as `true` like this: `arg2 = arg2 || "default;"`

Comment: If you pass only the first argument, the *variable* `arg2` will be defined, and its *value* will be `undefined`. You can find more gory details in [the ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3), if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the difference between *declared* variables and *defined* variables.

- a *declared* variable means that the variable name exists in the current scope, and refering to that variable by name will not produce a reference error
- a *defined* variable is a variable whose value is not `undefined`

A function's formal arguments are always *declared*, but they only *defined* if the function invocation is given defined values for those arguments.

Similarly, a variable declaration without any assignment like `var foo;` will make `foo` declared within its containing scope, but will not provide `foo` with a defined value.

For a more comprehensive, specificatioon-oriented overview of formal argument and the `arguments` variable, see [thefoutheye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22892050/710446).

Comment: `a defined variable is a variable whose value is not undefined`, how about `var a = undefined`? ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye, also, `var a;console.log(a);` is undefined

Comment: this answer is misleading for OP.

Answer (score 3):

```
function foo(bar) {
    console.log(bar);
    console.log(baz);
}

> foo()
< undefined
< ReferenceError: Can't find variable: baz
```

Arguments are always "defined" but may have the value `undefined`. Undefined variables are truly undefined and cause errors.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a function, all the parameters you define are called *Formal Parameters*. When you invoke the function, you will get pass a list of arguments. At runtime,

1. if the number of arguments match the number of Formal parameters, each formal parameter will have the argument corresponding to it.
2. if the number of arguments is greater than the number of formal parameters, rest of the arguments passed can be accessed only with [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) special variable.
3. if the number of arguments is lesser than then number of formal parameters, they will be assigned [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

So, to answer your question

> is the second argument arg2 defined but with value of undefined or is it entirely undefined

`arg2` is a formal parameter, and `undefined` is passed to it in your case.

**Reference** ECMA Standard Specification document, section [Declaration Binding Instantiation](http://es5.github.io/#x10.5).

Quoting from that,

> a. Let func be the function whose [[Call]] internal method initiated execution of code. Let names be the value of func’s [[FormalParameters]] internal property.
>
> b. Let argCount be the number of elements in args.
>
> c. Let n be the number 0.
>
> d. For each String argName in names, in list order do
>
> ```
>  i. Let n be the current value of n plus 1.
>
> ii. If n is greater than argCount, let v be undefined
>     otherwise let v be the value of the n’th element of args.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`arg2` will have just `undefined` but it is defined. When I say defined, I mean to say that you have defined the argument, but if not passed a value, it will have `undefined`

To proove,

let's make the function like this:

```
 var some_func = function(arg1, arg2) {
     alert(arg1); alert(arg2);
  }

 some_func('a'); // alerts a and undefined
 some_func('a','b'); // alerts a and b
```

Even more clarification:

```
var x; // defined but has undefined value will not throw error Result in undefined
y; // not defined and throws a value. Result in ReferenceError
```

In this case, `arg2` is like variable `x`